# React: how to link to a different component (to be open in the same page)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple app that has two pages: one for login and another for registration. I want them to have links to each other. As I know that React links have a different rationale, I'd lie to have the view of experienced colleagues regarding how to do it. This the code of `login-view`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import axios from 'axios';
import './login-view.scss';
import { RegistrationView } from '../registration-view/registration-view';

export function LoginView(props) {
  const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('');
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');
// need to update handleSubmit to prevent refresh
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Send a request to the server for authentication */
    axios.post('https://flix-app-test.herokuapp.com/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.data;
        props.onLoggedIn(data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('no such user')
      });
  };

    const handleNewUser = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('new_user');

      setUsername('New');
      props.onLoggedIn(username);
    };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>myFlix Login</h1>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicUsername">
          <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter username" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </div>

  );
}

LoginView.propTypes = {
  username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  password: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Here is the code of `registration-view`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { LoginView } from '../login-view/login-view';
import './registration-view.scss';

export function RegistrationView(props) {
  const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('');
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail ] = useState('');
  const [birthday, setBirthday ] = useState('');
// need to update handleSubmit to prevent refresh
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(username, password, email, birthday);
    /* Send a request to the server for authentication */
    /* then call props.onLoggedIn(username) */
    props.onLoggedIn(username);

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Signup for myFlix</h1>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="formUsername">
          <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter the username you want to use" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter a password" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter email" />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </Form.Text>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBirthday">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="date" value={birthday} onChange={e => setBirthday(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter your birthday date" />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
RegistrationView.propTypes = {
  username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  password: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  birthday: PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

I am allowed to use any package like `react-router-dom` so no restrictions at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could easily achieve that using `react-router`. First in a component which lies on top of the tree (usually `App`) you configure your Router, mapping each `path` to a specific component

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Login, Registration } from './components'

const App = () =>{
    return(
        <Router>
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/registration' component={Registration} />
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Now to change between routes inside your components you have several options. One of them is `Link` component

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
const Login = () =>{
    return(
        <Link to='/registration'>
            Go to registration
        </Link>
    )
}
```

To a more imperative API you should know that every component rendered by a router is injected with special props: `history`, `match` and `location`. To change the current route from inside a handler you can use `history.push`

```
const handleClick = () =>{
    props.history.push('/registration')
}
```

> The path to the components syntax on  is supposed to
>   be the same one I use to import the components?

Not it doesn't. The absolute path of your components has nothing to do with the `path` provided to `Router`

```
import { Foo } from './foo'
/*...*/
<Route path='/bar' />
```

> When implementing `Login` if I try to render it, it says I should not
>   use link outside router

I forgot to mention that to use `Link` you must be inside a Router context. Which means that the component from where you're calling `Link` (in your case `Login`) must be rendered by a router. In other words, it must be routed, defined inside one of your `Route` components.

Comment: thousand thanks in advance, but two more questions: 1) the path to the components syntax on `<Route path=...>` is supposed to be the same one I use to import the components; 2) when I implement `Login` if I try to render it, it says I should not use `link outside router`. What would you advice and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe we can use `react-scroll`

```
import * as Scroll from 'react-scroll';
import { Link, Element } from 'react-scroll''; 

<ScrollLink to="footerContainer">
     <Button className="hero-content-button" variant="info">Know More</Button>
</ScrollLink>

<Element name="footerContainer">
    <Footer />
</Element>
```

`ScrollLink` is imported from `react-scroll` which will link the button to footerContainer

everytime the button is clicked screen will scroll down to footer component

Comment: That's a cool library but it doesn't really help in that scenario.